# executing a bash script from a jsp page

Tags: javascript, bash, jsp, tomcat

I have previously written a bash script that executes a java class, it does other checks before running that class.
when running it takes arguments; `./SyncIPs.cmd 10.0.1.45` and executes few commands.

I am trying to run this script in a jsp page using a html/javascript button. I have so far, two jsp files as follows:

portal.jsp:

```
      <%
      if(request.getParameter("submitted")==null)
  {

    if(check)
    {

        %><%@include file="Sync.jsp" %><%
    }
    else
    {

        %><%@include file="Sync.jsp" %><%
    }   
 }
     %>
```

Sync.jsp:

```
   <%
   if(request.getParameter("submit") == null)
   {

   %>
    <div class=display>this is the Sync</div>

    </div>

    <br>
    <form method="POST" action="/project/jsp/Portal.jsp" id=form2>


  <input type=hidden name=sync>
      <!---this is where I want my script to be run from,--->

   <input type="button" value="" name="submit" action="run" 
   onClick="if(runOnSubmit()){getSomethingWithAjax
   ('Portal.jsp'+getAllFormElementsAndMakeIntoURI(true),
   '','hereIsTheMainHeaderSpan',false,false);}">
   <%
   }//end if
   %>
```

How do I get this script to run and get posted on the portal.jsp page?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use jQuery.  To make an ajax GET request, use [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put some java code in your .jsp

```
try {
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path_to_your_script/SyncIPs.cmd 10.0.1.45");
  p.waitFor();
  System.out.println("exit code: " + p.exitValue());
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

NOTE: be aware of possible security issues

Answer (score 0):

Using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` may be what you need.

HTH